# How to Check Numlock State of Virtual TTYs Without Elevated Privileges?

Tags: bash, shell, permissions, tty

I am trying to get the numlock states of multiple virtual TTYs. But my normal user account doesn't have read permission for some of them.

```
$ for tty in /dev/tty{1..6}; do setleds < ${tty} | grep "^Current flags:.*NumLock on"; echo $?; done
Current flags:          NumLock on    CapsLock off   ScrollLock off
0
Current flags:          NumLock on    CapsLock off   ScrollLock off
0
bash: /dev/tty3: Permission denied
1
bash: /dev/tty4: Permission denied
1
bash: /dev/tty5: Permission denied
1
bash: /dev/tty6: Permission denied
1
```

Is there any way to get this information without elevated privileges?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, because those ttys do not belong to your account, therefore reading their state requires privileges. (For example, being in the `tty` group.)